# How to Change stars of rating bar to another image

Tags: android

I have been trying to create a rating bar with varying ratings and there will be many rating bars.. So I created the rating bar dynamically using java codes.. But the problem is i can't change that star image to any other image. My code is below. I tried that commented line to change picture.. but it is not working.. It's setting only one picture as like background (full length of rating bar). How can I change each stars to any other picture? Thanks in advance.

```
        rating[i] = new RatingBar(this);
        rating[i].setLayoutParams(ratingparas);
        rating[i].setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        rating[i].setNumStars(ratingnumbr[i]);
        rating[i].setStepSize((float) 1.0);
    //  rating[i].setProgressDrawable(getResources()
    //          .getDrawable(R.drawable.box));
        rating[i].setTag("Ratingbar");
        svhorizontal[i].addView(rating[i]);
```

Comment: Something like [http://stackoverflow.com/q/5800657/1693947](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5800657/1693947)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2215186/1099716